# How to compare two dict and check if there is new item

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

How to compare two dict and check if there is new item, for example in second dict there is CCC, how to compare and get CCC in new variable.

```
dict1 = {'AAA': '0.23444', 'BBB': '0.5343'}
dict2 = {'AAA': '0.34343', 'BBB': '0.3435', 'CCC': '0.53322'}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "In a new variable"? a new dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find keys in `dict2` which do not occur in `dict1`, you can use the difference:

```
res = dict2.keys() - dict1.keys()

{'CCC'}
```

You can then access the key-value combinations via this set:

```
res_d = {k: dict2[k] for k in res}

{'CCC': '0.53322'}
```

Note, that in Python 3, `dict.keys()` is a view that can be used directly as if it were a set, which is why conversion to `set` is unnecessary.

You can also use a dictionary comprehension to combine these steps:

```
res_d = {k: dict2[k] for k in dict2.keys() - dict1.keys()}
```

Comment: As an additional note, you can use symmetric_difference to find both additions and subtractions.

Answer (score 0):

```
'''
OP wants to compare too dicts. If there is a different (new) key in one of the
dicts, he wants to add that value to dict1
'''

dict1 = {'AAA': '0.23444', 'BBB': '0.5343'}
dict2 = {'AAA': '0.34343', 'BBB': '0.3435', 'CCC': '0.53322'}

for key, value in dict2.items():
   if key not in dict1:
      dict1[key] = value

print(dict1)
```

We can iterate through each key in the second dict, and if it does not appear in the first dict, we can add it at the end. Here is the output:

```
{'AAA': '0.23444', 'BBB': '0.5343', 'CCC': '0.53322'}
```